# How to open a database (.crypt8) file?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, karbonn

I have to open a database (.crypt8) file in my computer. I followed this video "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5WViK3dTiAo", but this method it requires root access to work. How could I achieve this?

Comment: Have you thought about rooting your phone?

Comment: @1990clb  i have not root my phone.